# Details about the "I Am Dracula" young adult book

Tags: books, young-adult, character-identification, dracula

I read this book nearly 2 decades ago, **I Am Dracula** which blended various supernatural elements to show how Vlad the Impaler actually *became* the King of Vampires. He apparently was "soul mated" to a mystic gypsie girl, Zigane, in Walachia, finding this out when she astral projected to him as a boy. He then endured hardships growing up very much in line with the historical Vlad before she, now a full fledged witch, found him and lead him on the path. There were a **lot** of supernatural references and liberties taken; Dracula was made a Vampire by *Zigane* , who was made a Vampire by some large batwinged creature that came out of a lake, and they got further mystical powers by serving the devil, including a "sun sheld spell" which is why Dracula could exist in the sunlight, evenn being a vampire.

Can anyone clearly define all the supernatural creatures in the book, as well as where they hail from in terms of their mythology [I'm guessing the Wing serpant was an interpretation of Quetzalcoatl, the Mayan God, but I'm lost on the others].  Also, is the **I Am Frankenstien** book made by the same author?

Comment: Seriously;?  "Zigane?"  That literally means "gypsy."  A gypsy named "Gypsy;" how creative.

Comment: I’ve voted to close as unclear. This is tagged like a story identification?

Comment: presumably the winged serpent is intended to be a dragon, the main winged serpents of European myth. Dragons have are associated with Dracula as well (due to the name; the Romain "Dracul" can be translated to dragon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second part can be answered simply as yes. Both books are by [the same author](https://www.goodreads.com/author/show/286427.C_Dean_Andersson) as per the blurb for *[I Am Frankenstein](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/629551)*

> Andersson continues the bestselling tradition of *I Am Dracula* with the terrifying "true" story of Victor Frankenstein and his monstrous creation. In this unique retelling of the legendary tale, the story is told in two voices--revealing both Frankenstein and his monster's points-of-view.